# select Attribute by value

Tags: xpath, xml-attribute

Given this simple xml:

```
<root>  
    <child id="foo" />  
    <child id="bar" />  
</root>
```

I want to select the attribute with value = foo.
This xpath works: `root/child[@id='foo']/@id` but it seems there should be a way to accomplish the same without redundantly specifying the attribute name. Is it possible?

I've seen many discussions on finding an element using an attribute value; but in this case I want to return the attribute itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
root/child/@id[. = 'foo']
```

A dot means the current *node*, it doesn't necessarily have to be an *element*.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I thought it would be something simple. Once I knew what to search, I quickly found: [xpath-punctuation](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/xpath-punctuation-part-1). Thanks.